# Update total price?

Tags: javascript

I want a price to update when I click a button, that's all I want it to do, but everytime I try to call the value of my var, it returns "NotANumber/NaN" value, I've looked around for a little while but google get's a little bit confused and throws be tutorials about finding defined numbers, etc.

I am new to JavaScript, however. So it is probably me.

If anybody could help me out I'd be really grateful.

**total price:**

```
<span id="totalpriceex">0</span>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function incrementquan'.$row["pid"].'(){
    var input = document.getElementById("quan'.$row["pid"].'");
    input.value = parseInt(input.value) + 1;
    var element = document.getElementById("price'.$row['pid'].'");
    element.innerHTML = (" &pound;" + (input.value * '.$row['pprice'].').toFixed(2));
    var totalis = document.getElementById("totalprice");
    totalis.value = parseInt(totalis.value);
    totalis.innerHTML = (totalis.value + '.$row["pprice"].');
    var totalpriceex = parseInt(totalpriceex.value);
    totalpriceex.innerHTML = (totalis.value + '.$row["pprice"].'.toFixed(2))
var price=document.getElementById("totalpriceex");
price.value=price.value + '.$row["pprice"].'.toFixed(2);
}
```

I'm stuck! if you need anything else please leave a comment! Need this fixed as soon as I can, I'll keep trying in the mean time.

Comment: complete code please !

Comment: Looks like you're using PHP - wrap the PHP statements with <?php tags ?> - so <?php echo $row["pprice"] ?>

Comment: `totalpriceex` doesn't have a value. I'd make a variable `value` equal to `parseInt(totalis.innerHTML)` and that will equal 0. `totalis.innerHTML = ...` is not doing what you think, unless your trying to reset the text of `totalpriceex`

Comment: When parsing numbers in javascript it's best to explicit set the radix, you can get unexpected conversions if you are not careful. use this: `var int = parseInt(myValue, 10);`

Comment: you can call value method on form elements only...other elements you need to get value using textContent method

Comment: seems @user2182349 is right, you need to wrap your variables inside php tags ..huh ?

Comment: And be sure the file name ends with .php, not .html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call value method on form elements only...other elements you need to get value using textContent method

for form elements

```
$("input").val();
```

for other elements

```
$("span").text()
```

Comment: Wouldn't `element.innerText || element.textContent;` return a boolean value or is that just some javascript craziness?

Comment: || what was that for ?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp [No booleans](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Description). Logical operators in JS return an operand.

Comment: @Teemu Thanks. I was unfamiliar with that feature of js.

Comment: var text = element.innerText || element.textContent;  innerText will work only in IE but textContent works with other browsers...now, when other browsers return innerText as undefined means false then it will take textContent